# Owl Carousel 2 with mousewheel.js and no loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, owl-carousel, mousewheel

I'm using Owl Carousel 2 with mousewheel.js and it's working just fine.
I also managed to make it work setting loop: false

My problem comes when I scroll to the last or the first slide: my mouse stops working and I can not scroll over the page unless my mouse is outside the carousel space. How can I make the mouse work scrolling over the page as usual when I go to either the first or the last slide?
Should I detach and re-attach mousewheel event listener everytime I go to the end or the begining of the carousel?

Here is my code so far:

```
           let owl = document.getElementsByClassName('owl-stage'),
                nestedChildren = $(this).find('.owl-item').length;

            owl[0].addEventListener('mousewheel', e => {
                var activeSlideIndex= $(this).find('.owl-item.active').index() + 1;
                
                if (e.deltaY > 0 && nestedChildren > activeSlideIndex) {
                    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('next.owl', [0, 300]);
                } else if (e.deltaY < 0 && nestedChildren > activeSlideIndex) {
                    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('prev.owl', [0, 300]);
                }
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before your if else statement, check if you're on the first/last slide and if the scroll direction is trying to scroll out of the carousel. If so, break out of the eventListener and have the scroll wheel behave as normal. Otherwise, continue into your existing if else statement.